# Problema al recargar pagina

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo mis rutas configuradas, al usarlas de forma directa funcionan muy bien, pero tengo dos de ellas que al recargar la pagina o refrescarla, aparece un error, como este, 1."", no se que significa eso, sin embargo tambien paso lo que muestra arriba.

https://paste.laravel.io/9ade2d63-3143-4e96-9262-d8c4b2069ebc
estas son mis rutas https://paste.laravel.io/0664b7d2-b696-4b04-9dea-be905b16ebb5
y este mi controlador https://paste.laravel.io/f055568c-57f4-46e1-b694-8713371eb7b0

Comment: puedes poner la captura del error?

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/9ade2d63-3143-4e96-9262-d8c4b2069ebc  sale esto, en donde se supone que sale errores solo sale esto 1.""